# cuda should a unique block index and its calculation be moved to shared memory?

Tags: cuda, synchronization, gpu-shared-memory

Lets say we have a kernel that needs a unique block index and should scale as much as possible so it should scale across a 3D grid.

The calculation looks pretty complex, let just one thread perform it and store it in shared memory. Is it a good idea?
In all literature its always stored in registers, but whats the drawback in shared memory?

I am not sure but is shared memory read write access 4 cycles while a register is 1 cycle?

**Instead of:**

```
__global__ kernel()
{
    //get unique 3D block index
    const unsigned long long int blockId = blockIdx.x //1D
        + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x //2D
        + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z; //3D
}
```

**Maybe use: (assuming only x-dimension of block is used)**

```
__global__ kernel()
{
    __shared__ unsigned long long int blockId_s;

    if(threadIdx.x == 0)
        blockId_s = blockIdx.x //1D
            + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x //2D
            + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z; //3D
    __syncthreads();
}
```

This would save one register per thread which are costly at compute capability 1.x.

I have no tests and no idea if its good or bad for performance. 
The one more available register on cc 1.x is an argument but performance should be little slower with a `__syncthreads()` statement.

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it and see what it does? Shared memory is slower than the register file, so it will probably impact performance, but by how much will probably depend on the code and hardware.

Comment: Had to reinstall computer last days, so no CUDA installed. Maybe someone already had results.

Comment: @djmj did you ever try this experiment?

Comment: Not yet, could not find time for it, have to do some CUDA the next 3 weeks for my study but I have no up to date card to make reasonable tests (just a 1.1 card). The most interesting test case is when one more register would be needed that would be stored in local memory.

Comment: I honestly think that such a simple calculation is fine to do in every thread. But only an experiment will tell.

Comment: Oh man i wasted an hour to test it just to realize that the saved register resulted in more blocks per sm and so the speedup was  predictable. Next time different kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the answer was yes, but mostly because the resulting code used fewer registers and this allowed for higher overall occupancy and some speed up. This was despite the code having some branch divergence in the first warp, plus a synchronisation primitive.

However, this shouldn't be considered to be a universal rule and the only way to be sure is to write the code and benchmark it on the target GPU.

*This answer was added from comments as a community wiki entry  to get this question off of the unanswered queue.*

Answer (score -3):

In case of shared men you will have n-way bank conflict (n=WarpSize) each time you will access blockId_s. [CUDA C Programming Guide, 5.3.2.3]

And + shared mem is slower than register.

Comment: No bank conflict due to broadcast.